# Matches all links as incorrect - python validators

Tags: python, validation, python-requests

Tried to do a validation with help of `py.validators`, but any link I enter without protocol being matched as incorrect..

code:

```
import re, requests, validators
from collections import Counter
from prettytable import PrettyTable

url_input = str(input("Enter url: ").strip())

if not url_input.startswith(("http://", "https://")):
    try:
        url = "https://" + url_input
    except:
        url = "http://"  + url_input
 
response = requests.get(url)

validators.url(url_input)
if not validators.url(url_input):
    print("Entered link is not correct...")
    quit()

result = re.findall( r"\"(?:http[s]?://)([^:/\s\"]+)/?[^\"]*\"", response.text)
result.sort()

pt = PrettyTable(field_names=["word", "counter"])
pt.add_rows(list(Counter(result).most_common()))
print(pt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenating protocol as `url = "https://" + url_input` but then validate `url_input` that doesn't have it. You should just add protocol to `url_input` and use it everywhere instead of `url` variable.

Internally validator checks for protocol and since `url_input` doesn't have it, validation fails.

Comment: it gives me a block that returns “Entered link is not correct...”, that means it stops there not even reaching regex. Or please return me a code